# Is there an equivalent in RAD Studio Delphi's FMX for the VCL.MinimizeName function?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, vcl

I am writing an app for Windows/Mac/iOS/Android and I need to find a way to minimize a long path and filename for display in a TLabel. The VCL library has a MinimizeName function for this, but VCL is not available in anything other than Windows. Is there an equivalent for this in the FireMonkey FMX libraries?

Comment: Copy the source code for the `MinimizeName` function from the `vcl.filectrl.pas` to a new unit in your project, and use it in your FMX project.

Comment: Just note that you won't be able to copy/paste the code **as-is**, since `MinimizeName()` depends on a VCL `TCanvas` to determine the display width of the truncated string. So you would have to adjust that logic for FMX, at least.

Comment: I already tried that. I am surprised Embarcadero didn't port such a useful feature from VCL to FMX. I decided to strip the path and use the filename only.